# MVC Routing Issue - refreshing same page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, page-refresh

I have an Edit page and once the form is submitted I'm refreshing the page instead of redirecting the user to the Index page. To do so I'm saving the ID of the item in a temp variable and then use it to redirect the user to the edit page using the temp variable ID. Something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
{
    TempData["CategoryID"] = id;
    Category c = new CategoriesBL().GetCategory(id);
    return View(c);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Category c)
{
    new CategoriesBL().UpdateCategory(c);
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", (Guid)TempData["CategoryID"]);
}
```

That's working fine. However I have two methods in a different form on the same page and whenever I submit either of these two methods the redirection is not working and I'm getting an exception.

One of the methods that's not working:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddNewThumbnail()
{
    List<byte[]> thumbs = new List<byte[]>();

    for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
    {
        thumbs.Add(ConvertToByteArray(Request.Files[i].InputStream));
    }

    new CategoriesBL().AddCategoryThumbnail(thumbs, (Guid)TempData["CategoryID"]);
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", (Guid)TempData["CategoryID"]);
}
```

Exception:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid'....

I think it's an issue with routing but the fact is that the same implementation is used and it's working on one form and not the other. I'm not sure whether I'm doing something wrong or if there's any better way to do this.

Note: I have debugged the code several times and the ID I'm passing to the method does have a value in it. However when the page reloads the URL has no ID present.

**Debugging**

The problem seems to be due to the different forms I'm using. The first form I'm just editing text and it is like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    // ....
}
```

In the second form I'm saving and uploading images so the form has to be different

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddNewThumbnail", "Category", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
    // ....
}
```

Somehow when I changed the form to the 'normal' one everything worked. But of course I can't use it as I want to save images from this form.

Comment: Let us show your `AddNewThumbnail()` with `GET` request

Comment: There is no `AddNewThumbnail()` with `GET` request. The only `GET` request I have is the `Edit(Guid id)` method.

Answer (score 0):

pass the value from your view. Something like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Category c, FormCollection f)
{
   Guid categoryID =  (Guid)f["catergoryID"];
   new CategoriesBL().UpdateCategory(c);
   return RedirectToAction("Edit", catergoryID);
}
```

Comment: The Post method for the Edit method works with TempData. The problem is with the AddNewThumbnail() method.

Comment: I tried what you've suggested and it still didn't work. It's a weird problem, the only reason I can find is the form I'm using but still the retrieved ID isn't null.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you have initialisation:

`TempData["CategoryID"] = id;`

in `GET` method. So, you have to init your `(Guid)TempData["CategoryID"]` before you try to access it here:

`return RedirectToAction("Edit", (Guid)TempData["CategoryID"]);`

Comment: As I already mentioned when I debugged the code the ID is not null. It's just very strange behavior. Prior to `return RedirectToAction("Edit", (Guid)TempData["CategoryID"]);` in the `AddNewThumbnail()` method I'm saving `(Guid)TempData["CategoryID"]` as an ID in the database and it's not null.